# A problem based on number theory?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If 'p' is a prime greater than 3, then show that 2p + 1 and 4p + 1 cannot be primes simultaneously. 
Do I have to use Fermat's Little Theorem to solve this?

Comment: No. Try out some examples and see what happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A HINT**

$$p >3 \Leftrightarrow p \not \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$

$$p \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \Leftrightarrow 2p+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$

$$p \equiv 2 \pmod 3 \Leftrightarrow 4p+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$